# Is there an interpreter and auto-complete tool for golang like ptpython?

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang,  I want to learn by practicing Golang codes in my shell, is there an **interpreter** and **auto-complete** tool like `ptpython` for golang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an interpreter (it's a compiled language) or REPL for Go, but there is the go playground https://play.golang.org/ for trying out code.

And for autocomplete, there is a variety of tools out there depending on your editor; I use emacs:

> M-x package install go-autocomplete:

```
(ac-config-default)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(require 'go-autocomplete)
```

If you want a **REPL** *and*/*with* **autocomplete**, the best I can point you towards is an extension for the go play ground (if you using chrome):
[Better Go Playground](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-go-playground/odfhkelcmblecfdnboahphiafolojmpl)

It advertises:

> - Golang syntax highlighting
> - Replaces the built in with the Ace editor
> - Mark lines with syntax errors when running your code
> - Auto-completion + Snippets
> - Auto-save to local storage
> - Dark/Light theme toggle

all in a REPL like environment (you can't do networking stuff though)

Comment: Thanks so much，you are really a kind man!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vim:

Please check this out :

[vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go), [gocode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode) and [gotools](https://github.com/golang/tools)

[vim-go](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/vimgo-development-environment/) docs